# Reb Yitzhak's diamond, Rashi's birth - the source?

Tags: sources-mekorot, rashi, agada-stories-legends, story-identification

There's a famous story, mentioned [here](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/111831/jewish/Rashi-Rabbi-Shlomo-Yitzchaki.htm) and in many other places – the legend of Reb Yitzhak's diamond. What's the source of this story?

Tizku lmitvois!

Comment: This story is so famous that I’ve never heard of it before. Are we sure that this is on-topic here and that it’s not “Jews not Judaism”?

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Gamliel and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. In general it is helpful for questions to be self-contained, i.e., not to force people to look on an external site and search for a specific paragraph to understand what you mean. Welcome again and great to have you learn with us!

Comment: I agree with @DonielF. As currently worded, the question does not appear to relate to Judaism. If the question is [edit]ed to show how the story relates to Judaism then it would be on topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The source is [Shalshelet Hakabala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gedaliah_ibn_Yahya_ben_Joseph) p. [111](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=6618&st=&pgnum=120) (published 1587), who quotes it from an old manuscript.

Unlike the story you linked, he says that the priest wanted to buy it from him to use for the eye of an idol (I assume that's what עין פלו[ני] means), not for a cross. This version also doesn't have the heavenly voice compare his wisdom to King Solomon.